# jQuery selector with :not()

Tags: jquery, selector

How can I select all "input" elements in td except input in last td element?

```
'<div class="ui-widget" id="security-content">'+
    '<table class="ui-details-content ui-widget ui-widget-content">'+
    '<tr>'+
      '<td class="ui-state-default">{{Lng:options->user->security->newpass}}</td>'+
      '<td class="clear" id="sec-newpass" def=""><input type="text" class="ui-widget-content" value=""></td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
      '<td class="ui-state-default">{{Lng:options->user->security->repeatpass}}</td>'+
      '<td class="clear" id="sec-repeatpass" def=""><input type="text" class="ui-widget-content" value=""></td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
      '<td class="ui-state-default">{{Lng:options->user->security->passkey}}</td>'+
      '<td class="clear" id="sec-passkey"><input type="text" class="ui-widget-content" value="{{U:PassKey}}" disabled="disabled"></td>'+
    '</tr>'+
  '</table>'+
'</div>'
```

here is my selector:

```
$(#security-content td input:not(:last)')
```

Comment: You're missing your opening quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all input except inputs inside last td

```
$("#security-content td:not(:last) input")​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJhRh/2/)